# AJAX Google Map doesn't load

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, html-framework-7

I have this two files:

mappa2.html:

#map {
            height: 85%;
          }

```
    </style>

<script>
function showHint() {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "sql2.php", true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }

</script>



    <!-- Required meta tags-->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
    <!-- Your app title -->
    <title>Moli.se</title>
    <!-- Path to Framework7 Library CSS, iOS Theme -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="res/dist/css/framework7.ios.min.css">
    <!-- Path to Framework7 color related styles, iOS Theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="res/dist/css/framework7.ios.colors.min.css">
    <!-- Path to your custom app styles-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/my-app.css">

  </head>
  <body onload="showHint()">
    <!-- Status bar overlay for full screen mode (PhoneGap) -->
    <div class="statusbar-overlay"></div>
    <!-- Views -->
    <div class="views">
      <!-- Your main view, should have "view-main" class -->
      <div class="view view-main">
        <!-- Top Navbar-->
        <div class="navbar">
          <div class="navbar-inner">
             <div class="left">
            <a href="#" class="open-left-panel">
                <img src="img/list.png" />
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="center"><a href="#"><img src="http://moli.se/wp/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/logo-molipuntose-2016-160.png" height="30"/></a></div>

          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Pages container, because we use fixed-through navbar and toolbar, it has additional appropriate classes-->
        <div class="pages navbar-through">
          <!-- Page, "data-page" contains page name -->
          <div data-page="index" class="page">
            <!-- Scrollable page content -->
            <div class="page-content">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Mappa</div>
                    <div class="card-content">
                        <div class="card-content-inner">
                        <!--Inzio mappa -->
                     <div id ="txtHint"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div> </div> 
                </div></div>  </div> 
 </div>
    <div class="panel-overlay"></div>
    <!-- Left panel, let it be with reveal effect -->
    <div class="panel panel-left panel-reveal">
        <div class="content-block">
      <p>Benvenuto su Moli.se</p>
     <a href="index.html" class="external"> <p>Home</p></a>
     <a href="mappa.html" class="external"> <p>Mappa</p></a>     
     <a href="http://moli.se/blog" class="external"> <p>Blog</p></a>    </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Path to Framework7 Library JS-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="res/dist/js/framework7.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Path to your app js-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/moli-se.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And sql2.php:

```html
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect('*******','******','*****','*************');
if (!$con) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_select_db($con,"ajax_demo");
$sql="SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM posti";
$result=mysqli_query($con ,$sql ); $data=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$d = $data['total'];
echo "
<div id='map'></div>";
echo "
<script>
function initMap() {
        var uluru = {lat: 42.5 , lng: 14.5 };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 8,
          center: uluru
        });

var noPoi = [
{
    featureType: \"poi\",
    stylers: [
      { visibility: \"off\" }
    ]   
  }
];

map.setOptions({styles: noPoi});  
";
for ($i = 1 ; $i <= $d ; $i++) {
$sel="SELECT * FROM posti WHERE id = '".$i."'";
$res = mysqli_query($con,$sel);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($res);
echo "
var uluru" .$i . " = {lat: " .$row['latitudine'] .", lng: " .$row['longitudine'] ."};

var contentString" . $i . " = ' <div id=\"content\"><h2> " . $row['name'] . "</h2></div>'
var infowindow"  .$i . "= new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: contentString" . $i . "
        });

var marker" . $i . " = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: uluru" .$i .",
          map: map,
          title: 'Title',
          icon : 'yellow.png'

        });

        marker" . $i . ".addListener('click', function() {
          infowindow" .$i .".open(map, marker" . $i . ");
        });

";
}
echo "
}
</script>
<script async defer
    src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?MY_KEY=initMap'>
    </script>



";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

If I load mappa2.html, the map doesn't load. But if I copy the generated code and put it in another html file, the map shows up correctly.

If I write in the js console: `initMap()` it says:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: initMap is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

Comment: Please remove source code sections which are not needed in this question. That how, it is more efficient for users to solve your problem.

Comment: Here is a [little help](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/advice-for-non-native-english-speakers/291370#291370) to the high level internet communication.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it has to do with this `src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?MY_KEY=initMap'>` Shouldn't the maps api key be there?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<iframe
  width="350"
  height="250"
  frameborder="0" style="border:0"
  src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=yourapikey=<?php echo $your_keyword;?>" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

> [Get API Key](https://console.developers.google.com/projectselector/apis/credentials?pli=1) 
>   its working or not? give a quick response

Comment: I changed it When i was posting in stackoverlflow.It's correct in my code